# Dynamic way for redirect activity to another activity - android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an app that have a lot of `Adapter` I am using `setOnClickListener` for redirect from one activity to another activity.

**Problem** :

In each adapter I should write :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), another.class);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Can I use from a dynamic way for redirect from activity to another activity (sometimes I need to transfer some data between activities).

**Finally** :

I just write once and use in other activities.

Comment: **Wrap your intent code in a function** then call function where you need to recreate intent code

Comment: sometimes I need to transfer some data between activities.

Comment: You can pass data to an array or as string  to parameter of function

Comment: Not principled in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem if you have many activities. I solved it by using a singleton **Navigator** class like this:

```
public class Navigator {

  private static Navigator instance;

  private Navigator() {
  }

  public static Navigator getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      synchronized (Navigator.class) {
        if (instance == null) {
          instance = new Navigator();
        }
      }
    }
    return instance;
  }

  public void navigateToSubActivity(Context context, String data) {
    Intent subAct = SubActivity.getCallingIntent(context);
    // This is the data where you want to send to target activity.
    subAct.putExtra("DATA", data);
    context.startActivity(subAct);
  }
}
```

Then in every activity you should add static method like (here the example for `SubActivity` class):

```
/**
  * Returns the intent for this activity
  *
  * @param context {@link Context}
  * @return {@link Intent}
  */
public static Intent getCallingIntent(Context context) {
  return new Intent(context, SubActivity.class);
}
```

Finally, you can happily navigate to another activity by using:

```
Navigator.getInstance().navigateToSubActivity(this, "my data");
```

Please remember when you want to catch the bundled data previously sent, you need to add the following code in recipient Activity `onCreate()`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
mData = extras.getString("DATA");
// process the data after we receive it.
```

---

**Note:**

If my memory serves me, I guess this is a slight modification that I make from [Navigator class](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture/blob/master/presentation/src/main/java/com/fernandocejas/android10/sample/presentation/navigation/Navigator.java) from [Android-CleanArchitecture](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture) though without `injection`.

Comment: In one class I have just on data for pass and another multiple data(int,string,boolean) and etc...How I can manage it ?(Context context, String data)

Comment: That is simple, you need only to add another method like: `public void navigateToSubActivity(Context context, String data, String anotherData)`

Comment: @ישו אוהב אותך.Is this way stable , I know that the data will not be lost?

Comment: I'm not having any problem so far. This is  more compact solution than calling each Intent in the caller activity.

Comment: @ישו אוהב אותך.Thanks a lot .If my topic need to edit, edit it for use another users . thanks .

Answer (score 0):

i hope this code help you

**in Your Adapter class**

```
 private OnStatusChangeListener onStatusChangeListener;

    public void setOnStatusChangeListener(final OnStatusChangeListener onCartChangeListener) {
            this.onStatusChangeListener = onCartChangeListener;
    }

    public interface OnStatusChangeListener {
            public void onStatusChange(int position);
    }
```

in your Activity class

```
 yourAdapter.setOnStatusChangeListener(new yourAdapter.OnStatusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStatusChange(int position) {

//Do here what you pass data or anything beetween two activity or fragments

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayActivity.class);
            //Create a bundle object
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            //Inserts a String value into the mapping of this Bundle
            b.putString("name", name.getText().toString());
            b.putString("age", age.getText().toString());
            int id = genderRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
            b.putString("gender", radioButton.getText().toString());

            //Add the bundle to the intent.
            intent.putExtras(b);

            //start the DisplayActivity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
                }
            });
```